# How to remove duplicates from List without using set in java

Tags: java

Here i have list which contains duplicate values. but what i need is, list should not contain duplicate values. I tried many of the solutions from stack overflow. but didn't get any solution.    The below code is one of the code i have tried. but i didn't get the solution.

```
List<ReportsBean> list = rutils.getYearsReport(year);
list=========before=====5
LinkedHashSet<ReportsBean> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<ReportsBean>(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(lhs);
list=========after=====5
```

before and after same list size 5.
Please can any one help me.

Comment: What you've done should work.  Can you please show what the values in your list are, before and after you run this snippet?

Comment: How do you compare ReportsBean objects? Have you overriden equals() /hashCode() methods?

Comment: To really understand what is going on, we would need the ReportsBean class code. I guess: it doesn't provide proper equals() / hashCode() methods; and therefore the set is unable to remove "duplicates"; because all entries of the list are "unique".

Comment: windstorm,windstorm,fire,water,others-- there are the values i have in list

Comment: `indstorm,windstorm,fire,water,others` - that's some names and _not_ the actual `ReportsBean` instances. Post the `equals()` and `hashCode()` of `ReportsBean` - if you don't have any then that's the problem (unless some superclass that is not Object defines them).

Comment: But i am assigning values to bean only and i need to retrieve values from bean only na @jagermeister

Comment: That is one thing with programming: the language and the runtime do not care what you **intended** to do. If **you** put objects of a certain class into a set, and you expect the set to remove duplicates, then **you** have to make sure that your class provides appropriate equals/hashCode methods. Otherwise you get exactly ... what you got here: you are using a set, but because all objects look "different", the set can't remove duplicates. And there is no point in you claiming "but I want to"; because, as said: that doesn't matter. What matters is what your code **is** doing.

Comment: [com.s2s.bssb.bean.ReportsBean@676a3f, com.s2s.bssb.bean.ReportsBean@1707a6a, com.s2s.bssb.bean.ReportsBean@174d546, com.s2s.bssb.bean.ReportsBean@15def9e, com.s2s.bssb.bean.ReportsBean@1e74ed] this is my hashCode @@jagermeister

Comment: Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in your class `ReportsBean`

Comment: @Asha Please stop here. First of all, there is no point in adding more information in comments; always update the question. Then: that output exactly shows your problem - you have 5 ReportBean objects; and all of them are "different". Please step back; and google about java collections, equals and hashCode and change your bean code accordingly. Anything else is a waste of your (and our) time.

Comment: @Asha how is your program supposed to know that com.s2s.bssb.bean.ReportsBean@676a3f and com.s2s.bssb.bean.ReportsBean@1707a6a are duplicates of each other?  They look like different objects to me.

Comment: @Asha regarding your last comment. If you would have properly overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()`, the hashcodes of equal objects would be equal as the contract for `hashCode()` defines it. This is especially important for things like `HashSet`s or `HashMap`s. So my answer below is exactly the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tested with the following code and it works like a charm:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "a"));
LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(lhs);
System.out.println(list);
```

I'd say the `equals()` method of your `ReportsBean` is not or wrongly overridden. (Btw. don't forget to also override `hashCode()` if you override `equals()`.